# What to use for Chat Application with Client-Server Architecture?

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, udp, client-server

I need to implement client/server chat application using pure sockets in Python with many different requirements for such a middleware.
The server should serve a small number of clients and I need to decide which sockets should I use TCP and/or UDP. Also I need to implement a multicast.

Answer (score 2):

You can use python's builtin [socket](https://realpython.com/python-sockets/) module
You should use TCP sockets for this purpose